# C# Double.ToString() wrong result

Tags: c#, string, format, tostring

I am trying to display a double value using ToString() methode.
the value is 1.000000000000113.
, using Double.ToString("F16") result 1.0000000000001100
, using Double.ToString("F17") result 1.00000000000011000

I tried it with 
Double.ToString("0.0000000000000000") result 1.0000000000001100

It seems that ToString() sets all fraction numbers above the 14-th number to zero.

I am using .Net 4.5.2.
How can I solve this problem.

Comment: Try to use Decimal

Comment: [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double) - pay careful attention to "precision".

Comment: thank you for the tip, i didn't focused on the double precision, because the I debugged the code and the debugger displayed the double number correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `float` and `double` floating point numbers ([IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)) work on a *Sign*, *Mantissa* and *Exponent* in *base 2*, it just so happens the number `1.000000000000113` doesn't fit into a *base 2* number.

However, we do have floating point types that **do** work on *base 10* (`decimal`), it has more precision for rational numbers, yet doesn't have the numeric range

- [`float`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/float) approximate Range    (`±1.5 x 10^−45` to `±3.4 x 1038`)
- [`double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/double) approximate Range   (`±5.0 × 10^−324` to `±1.7 × 10308`)
- [`decimal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal)    approximate Range   (`±1.0 x 10^-28` to `±7.9228 x 1028`)

**Sample**

```
double val = 1.000000000000113;
Console.WriteLine(val);
decimal val2 = 1.000000000000113m;
Console.WriteLine(val2);
```

**Output**

```
1.00000000000011
1.000000000000113
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7Tiupo)

Comment: Many Thank for the fast answer,